# Covariant derivative and exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

My question is why the covariant derivative on a trivial vector bundle is always given by the exterior derivative, since as far as I know the covariant derivative on a vector bundle is not uniquely defined !
In addition, what make me more confused is that on some references I find  that a covariant derivative $\nabla$ on a trivialisation is given by $\nabla = d + \theta$, where d is the exterior derivative and $\theta$ is a differential 1-form.

Please excuse me if my question is very basic! I greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: It’s not. A trivial vector bundle can be given the trivial connection but it can also be given other connectuons, as you say. You need to pick one.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan thank you  for confirming  this! Then I understand that the exterior derivative is the "canonical choice ".

Comment: Is the formula in the second part of the question  $\nabla =d +\theta  $, where $ \theta $ is a differential 1-form gives all possible covariant derivatives defined on a trivial bundle ?

Comment: Yes, on a trivial bundle connections can be identified with $1$-forms (and the curvature of the connection is the exterior derivative of the $1$-form). To be clear, these are $1$-forms valued in the endomorphism bundle.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Qiaochu Yuan for this clarification !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question: no, on a trivial vector bundle, there are covariant derivatives that are not "the exterior derivative". Generally, if there are two connections $\nabla, \nabla'$ on your vector bundle $E$, then their difference is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued 1-form, i.e. an element of $\Omega^1(M;\text{End}(E))$, and conversely, you can obtain a connection by adding such a 1-form to another connection. This means that the connections on $E$ form an affine space modelled on $\Omega^1(M;\text{End}(E))$, i.e. picking a base point (or *canonical* choice of connection) we can identify the two vector spaces.

The reason why I put "the exterior derivative" in quotes, btw., is that, since sections of $E$ take values in $E$, they are not real functions, and can therefore not really be differentiated. What is usually meant is that for a trivial bundle, there is usually a canonical choice $(e_1,\dots,e_r)$ of global frame (i.e. $r$ sections of $E$ that provide a basis in each point). In the case of $M\times\mathbb{R}^r$ those are usually defined as $e_i(p) := (p, \epsilon_i)$ where $\epsilon_i$ is the $i$-th unit vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Anyway, you can now define a connection $\nabla$ (the so-called *canonical connection*) by requiring that $\nabla_X e_i=0$ for all $i$. This implies that for any section $s=\sum_{i=1}^r f_i e_i$ the covariant derivative looks like $$\nabla_X s = \sum_{i=1}^r \nabla_X(f_ie_i) = \sum_{i=1}^r X(f_i)e_i + f_i\nabla_X e_i = \sum_{i=1}^r X(f_i)e_i = \sum_{i=1}^r df_i (X) e_i,$$
or in other words that $\nabla s = \sum_{i=1}^r df_i\otimes e_i$, which is where the shorthand $\nabla=d$ comes from. And since any connection can now be written as $\nabla+\theta$ for a suitable $\theta\in\Omega^1(M; \text{End}(E))$, this is where the shorthand of $d+\theta$ for a general connection comes from.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much @philip98 for your detailed answer.